# Python sqlite3: Loop through rows from table_a stops when inserting into table_b

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Trying to to loop through rows from table_a, pass them into a function, and insert the outputs into table_b. I can manage to loop through rows from table_a, but as soon as i try to insert to table_b something, my script just stops.

```
with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM cars""")

for row in cursor:
  car_price = get_car_price(row[0])
  cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO car_prices (price, car_id) VALUES (?,?);""",(car_price, row[0]))
```

**output :**

```
[Finished in 1.0s]
```

It is weird because the below works, but as soon as i try executing to car_prices table (as in the previous code), the code just ends at first iteration.

```
with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM cars""")

for row in cursor:
  print(row)
```

**output:**

```
(1, "car_1")
(2, "car_2")
...
(n, "car_n")
[Finished in 0.7s]
```

As asked, here is the .schema:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "cars" (
        "id"    integer NOT NULL,
        "name"  text NOT NULL,
        "website_url"   text NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "car_prices" (
        "price_id"      integer,
        "price" NUMERIC NOT NULL,
        "car_id"        integer NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY("price_id"),
        FOREIGN KEY("car_id") REFERENCES "cars"("id")
```

Comment: What's the .schema for your cars table? For example `INSERT INTO car_prices (price, car_id) SELECT price, car_id FROM cars;` works if you have matching column names. Without knowing your cars table scheme I can't be sure that SQL would work.

Comment: I don't know what a schema is so haven't created one.
cars table has two columns: car_id (PRIMARY KEY), and car_name.
car_prices table has three columns, price_id (PRIMARY KEY), price, car_id (FOREIGN KEY)
Hope this helps.

Comment: Run `sqlite3 mydatabasefile.db` then run a `.schema` command. Edit your question with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're reusing your cursor, throwing away the results of your first query.

Here's a [minimal runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (you may have gotten a faster answer if you had included this in your question, since it would've taken less effort for people to get involved):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sqlite3
import sys

def get_car_price(carid):
    return carid * 11 + 101

with sqlite3.connect(':memory:') as db:
    db.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "cars" (
            "id"    integer NOT NULL,
            "name"  text NOT NULL,
            "website_url"   text NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY("id")
        )
    ''')
    db.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "car_prices" (
            "price_id"      integer,
            "price" NUMERIC NOT NULL,
            "car_id"        integer NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY("price_id"),
            FOREIGN KEY("car_id") REFERENCES "cars"("id")
        )
    ''')
    for ix, name in enumerate(('Lolvo', 'Yotoya', 'Edison')):
        url = 'http://example.com/' + name.lower()
        db.execute('INSERT INTO cars VALUES(?,?,?)', (ix, name, url))

    cursor = db.cursor()
    if 'sep' in sys.argv:
        insertcursor = db.cursor()
    else:
        insertcursor = cursor


cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM cars""")
for row in cursor:
    car_price = get_car_price(row[0])
    print(row, car_price)
    insertcursor.execute("""INSERT INTO car_prices (price, car_id) VALUES (?,?);""",(car_price, row[0]))

cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM car_prices''')
for row in cursor:
    print('car_prices:', row)
```

Running with no args, it'll use the same cursor, reproducing your problem:

```
python-sqlite-stops$ ./stuff.py
(0, 'Lolvo', 'http://example.com/lolvo') 101
car_prices: (1, 101, 0)
```

Give it 'sep' as an arg, and it'll use a separate cursor for insertion, fixing your problem:

```
python-sqlite-stops$ ./stuff.py sep
(0, 'Lolvo', 'http://example.com/lolvo') 101
(1, 'Yotoya', 'http://example.com/yotoya') 112
(2, 'Edison', 'http://example.com/edison') 123
car_prices: (1, 101, 0)
car_prices: (2, 112, 1)
car_prices: (3, 123, 2)
```

You could make it even simpler by just using `db.execute()` for the inserts; no `cursor()` call necessary.